# Using JQuery to find the widths of all children under the body tag down to a specific generation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the widths of set of HTML elements on a web page.

Basically, I want to get the widths of:

1. The `html` element
2. The `body` element
3. All elements directly under the `body` element [ancestor]
4. All children directly under 'ancestor' down to the fourth generation (if at all it goes that far down)

So looking at the HTML code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>Test 1</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>Test 2
                            <div>Test 2 - Child</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can get the widths of `html`, `body`, and the 'ancestors' [(1), (2), and (3)] pretty easily with:

```
console.log($('html').outerWidth());
console.log($('body').outerWidth());
$('body').children().each(function(){
    console.log(this.outerWidth());
});
```

However, I'm not sure how to get the descendants of the 'ancestor' down to the 4th generation. So 4th generation would be where you have `Test 1` and `Test 2`, `Test 2 - Child` would be fifth generation.

**FYI** I'm doing this on pages that I cannot control so identifiers like `id` and `class` will not be available for me to target. Also the descendants may vary tag-wise, they might not always be `div`s.

Comment: You need to use a recursive function to go as deep as it needs to.

Comment: `$.each('div', function(k,v) { console.log('div #' + k + ': ' + $(this).html()) });`

Comment: @Tomanow Thanks. It is not guaranteed that the elements are going to be `div` tags

Comment: @scrowler Looking into that now

Comment: @ObinwanneHill here's a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/5SV9Z/1/ - not sure what you want to do with the data but this is targetting those two deepest elements and logging their widths to the console. You could use something like this, and target a fourth level element if you wanted to. Use a global variable to know how deep you are.

Comment: @scrowler Thanks, but it doesn't provide the width of every single descendant down to the 4th Generation, which is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to traverse the tree 3 times down. it's easy with recursion:

**EDIT**: fiddle contributed by asker: http://jsfiddle.net/WqupP/2/

```
function traverseDownBy(generations, start){ 
    var children = [],
        generation_num_start = generations+2,
        generation_num,
        counter = 0
        ;    
    function traverseDown(node){
        counter++;
        if(counter <= 1)
        {
            generation_num = generation_num_start;
        }
        else
        {
            generation_num--;
        }

        if(generation_num == 0){
            generation_num = generation_num_start;
            return;
        }        
        children.push(node);
        node.children().each( function () { traverseDown($(this)); } );
    }
    traverseDown(start);
    return children;
}
var children = traverseDownBy(4, $('body'));
$(children).each( function (){
    $('#result').append('<p>'+$(this).attr('id')+': '+$(this).width()+'</p>'); 
});
```

or even

```
(function(){ //private. member protection.
    var generations = 4;
    function traverseDown(node){
        generations--;
        if(generations == 0) return;
        console.log(node.outerWidth());
        node.children().each( function () { traverseDown($(this)); } );
    }
    traverseDown($('body'));
})()
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting inconsistent results. See this http://jsfiddle.net/Yt24J/1/ for more.

Comment: I found the solution. It's on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WqupP/2/. Can you update the code in your answer so I can accept it?! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got the problem...

Well, a bad solutions is to combine multiple instances of `.children()` function. Example:

```
var childrens = $('body').children().add(
    $('body').children().children().add(
        $('body').children().children().children().add(
            $('body').children().children().children().children()
        )
    )

childrens.each(blablah);
```

Source: [JQuery's "find()" with depth limit, I can't use .children()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880037/jquerys-find-with-depth-limit-i-cant-use-children)

[How to combine two jQuery results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323955/how-to-combine-two-jquery-results)

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
$('body').find('*').each(function(k,v) {
    console.log($(this).width());
});
```